# How do I split a list into a list of lists on a specific character in the elements?

Tags: python, list, split, nested-lists

I'm relatively new to programming and trying get a (very) long list of information into a table using Python. I installed [HTML.py from Decalage](http://www.decalage.info/en/python/html) and now need to get my list turned into into a list of lists that HTML.py can parse.

Is there an easy way to split a list like this:

`['(617) 965-2555<br />\nOrganization Name', 'Street Name', 'City', 'Zip code', '(413) 333-2251<br />\nOrg Name 2', 'Address', 'City', 'Zip code 2', '(617) 568-7777</p>\n\n']`

into a list of lists at "\n"?

So ideally the result would look like something like this:

`[ ['Previous info', '(617) 965-2555<br />']
['Organization name', 'Street name', 'City', 'Zip Code', '(413) 333-2251<br />']
['Org Name 2', 'Address', 'City', 'Zip Code 2', '(617) 568-7777</p>']
]`

Suggestions for an alternate method of getting that list into an organized table a la HTML.py would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> a
['(617) 965-2555<br />\nOrganization Name', 'Street Name', 'City', 'Zip code', '(413) 333-2251<br />\nOrg Name 2', 'Address', 'City', 'Zip code 2', '(617) 568-7777</p>\n\n']
>>> [i.split("\n") for i in a]
[['(617) 965-2555<br />', 'Organization Name'], ['Street Name'], ['City'], ['Zip code'], ['(413) 333-2251<br />', 'Org Name 2'], ['Address'], ['City'], ['Zip code 2'], ['(617) 568-7777</p>', '', '']]
```

If you want it flattened:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain(*[i.split("\n") for i in a]))
['(617) 965-2555<br />', 'Organization Name', 'Street Name', 'City', 'Zip code', '(413) 333-2251<br />', 'Org Name 2', 'Address', 'City', 'Zip code 2', '(617) 568-7777</p>', '', '']
```

Edit:

Thanks to @agf's comment, now I got it i think:

```
>>> a
['(617) 965-2555<br />\nOrganization Name', 'Street Name', 'City', 'Zip code', '(413) 333-2251<br />\nOrg Name 2', 'Address', 'City', 'Zip code 2', '(617) 568-7777</p>\n\n']
>>> [i.split("{}") for i in "{}".join(a).split("\n")]
[['(617) 965-2555<br />'], ['Organization Name', 'Street Name', 'City', 'Zip code', '(413) 333-2251<br />'], ['Org Name 2', 'Address', 'City', 'Zip code 2', '(617) 568-7777</p>'], [''], ['']]
```

Assuming "{}" is never used on your original list, else change it to something not in your list, `|`, `;:;` etc.

And you can easily filter the output for removing list contains just empty strings with:

```
filter("".join, result)
```

Comment: This isn't what he asked. He wants a list of lists, where each newline delineates a new sub- list.

Comment: Clever but prone to breakage if you can't predict what characters will / won't be used.

Comment: @agf, thanks, edited answer. Yes, it is error prone, but I think you can change it to `+%+'^23+ç.ü`, it's almost impossible for someone to enter. Or, you can even generate random ten characters and use it.

Comment: See @kindall 's comment on my question for an easier way to flatten too.

Comment: Thanks utdemir (and agf)--this worked perfectly and will make my day a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly convert your list easily on \n:

```
newlist = [a.split('\n') for a in oldlist]
```

But your results list isn't close enough to your source list for me to understand... where did "Previous info" come from?

Comment: oops, someone beat me to it ;-)

Comment: This also doesn't do what he want. It doesn't create sub-lists from each line.